# Cplex termination criteria

Tags: cplex, termination, opl

I have developed a MIP problem, while solving the problem. The model was running for hours without reaching the optimal solution. Thus, I have set a termination criteria to stop running after the gap is equal to 0.00005. Also, I have set barrier time limit, yet the running doesn't terminated. Here is the attached code used.

`execute {cplex.epgap = 0.00005;  }`

`execute {cplex.baritlim= 500;}`

`execute {cplex.optimalitytarget=3; }`

Is it any problem with the written termination code?

Comment: You may have set the time limit for the barrier, algorithm, but that would only limit the time allowed for using the barrier algorithm to solve the LP relaxations e.g. from the sub-problems at each node of the branch and bound tree. You need to set the overall time limit for the solve as Alex has suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply try:

```
execute {cplex.tilim= 500;}
```